# Как получить доступ клиента к сайту по ip адресу сервера?

Tags: администрирование, сетевое-администрирование, vipnet

Ситуация следующая, есть 2 компьютера(один в роли сервера, другой в роли клиента).На одном стоит `vipnet`,на другом не стоит.
Так вот, там где не стоит `vipnet`,доступ к спец. сайту осуществляется путём ввода в браузер адреса и порта(например `192.168.1.40:6024`) и в итоге происходит вход на сайт. Компьютеры друг друга видят в сети и `ping` проходит.

Но потом после перезагрузки доступа нет, скажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы снова восстановить его.
-Проброс портов или какая-нибудь команда через `cmd` типа `traceroute`..